# How to use certificates in savon 2.0.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, soap, savon

I recently update on savon 2.0.2 and I'm using it for sending some xml via soap. 
I have to use certificates but after updating the syntax of the new savon version the certificates are ignored. Could someone help me with the new syntax - I'm probably missing something... I'm running ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.9

Old (working) version:

```
client = Savon::Client.new do | wsdl |
  wsdl.endpoint = CONFIG['endpoint']
  wsdl.namespace = CONFIG['namespace']
end

  response = client.request(:ns, :getToken) do

    http.auth.ssl.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(
      File.read(Rails.root + "lib/certs/cert.pem"))
    http.auth.ssl.cert_key_file = Rails.root + "lib/certs/key.pem"
    http.auth.ssl.verify_mode = :none

    soap.body = {

      // body
    }
    soap.header={
      "ns:account"=>{
        :login=>CONFIG['login'],
        :password=>CONFIG['password']
      }      
    }
  end
```

Now I tried to do exactly the same in 2.0.2, but it's not working - xml is ok, but certificate is being ignored...

so far I got:

```
  client = Savon.client do
  endpoint CONFIG['endpoint']
  namespace CONFIG['namespace']
  namespace_identifier :ns

  ssl_cert_file OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(Rails.root + "lib/certs/cert.pem"))
  ssl_cert_key_file Rails.root + "lib/certs/key.pem"
  ssl_verify_mode :none


  soap_header(
      "sus:account"=>{
        :login=>CONFIG['login'],
        :password=>CONFIG['password']
      }      
   )

end

response = client.call(:getToken) do

      message(
     // body
        )

end
```

Any help would be very appreciated!!!

Comment: did you read this section of the docs? http://savonrb.com/version2.html#globals-ssl

Comment: This question covers something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15973285/does-savon-support-client-side-certificates-authentication

Comment: Update: it looks like Savon has since changed that document quite a bit. For those still using Savon2, perhaps for compatibility with an older app, here's a permalink: https://web.archive.org/web/20130112080003/http://savonrb.com/version2.html

Answer (score 0):

The use of `ssl_verify_mode :none` tells Savon to turn off SSL checking. That is why the cert is being ignored. As pointed out in the comments full documentation can be found on [the Savon site](http://savonrb.com/version2.html#globals-ssl).